# How to use infer to extract a common key from a union type?

Tags: typescript

I'm creating a library where I need to use a common type distinguished by name; I need to be able to get the names easily.

```
interface Base<T extends string> {
   name: T;
}

interface Foo extends Base<'Foo'> {}
interface Bar extends Base<'Bar'> {}
interface Baz extends Base<'Baz'> {}

export type FooBarBaz = Foo | Bar | Baz;

// I want to make a type, which is equivalent to this:
// export type FooBarBazTypes = 'Foo' | 'Bar' | 'Baz';

// But I want to do it with some magic infer stuff.

export type SomeMagicCrap<T>;

export type FooBarBazTypes = SomeMagicCrap<FooBarBaz > // Should be equivalent to 'Foo' | 'Bar' | 'Baz';
```

How can I extract `'Foo'`, `'Bar'` and `'Baz'`? I know it involves `infer` but I don't remember exactly how.

Comment: You don't need `infer` if you know `T` is constrained to `Base`, you can just write `type SomeMagicExcrement<T extends Base<any>> = T['name']`.  You *could* use `infer` like `T extends Base<infer U> ? U : never` but I'd avoid conditional types unless they're necessary.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is check whether values of the `FooBarBaz` union (`Foo | Bar | Baz`) extend `Base` and then `infer` the generic value passed to `Base` and return it to generate a new union from those string values.

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QDwBVkQAekIAJhshmFKAOYB8yA3gLABQyyIcAthAFzJcAbnYBfdu1CRYiFADEA9ooLEIZCuizYA5EsU7GTCW2nR4SNHCiqS5K9p3ooh5ibOzL6AF6319rRwnOG9XY0k2IgAHRSgwZDAATyiFZWcfZABeZH1kAB8rGwKfUTZ2JJTkAGVFPgBZOFpgBABhKDgovEZs-CI7TUwcUBhoZABVRgB+ceRBEAgAN2hS9mjY+IrUxXSQ3GSICmya+sbmto7sfR3vemFkAHp75D1lHXzn5zeC4NCgA)

```
interface Base<T extends string> {
  name: T;
}

interface Foo extends Base<'Foo'> {}
interface Bar extends Base<'Bar'> {}
interface Baz extends Base<'Baz'> {}

export type FooBarBaz = Foo | Bar | Baz;

type SomeMagicCrap<T> = T extends Base<infer U> ? U : never;

export type FooBarBazTypes = SomeMagicCrap<FooBarBaz>; // 'Foo' | 'Bar' | 'Baz'
```